# Concatenating strings in .emacs.bmk

Tags: string, emacs

Confused about this error:

**bookmark-bmenu-show-filenames: Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, (concat (getenv "TNS_ADMIN") "/tnsnames.ora")**

Context: I'm trying to edit an existing bookmark in standard .emacs.bmk file to use (concat (getenv "TNS_ADMIN")...) in place of a hardcoded pathname:

```
;;;; Emacs Bookmark Format Version 1 ;;;;
;;; This format is meant to be slightly human-readable;
;;; nevertheless, you probably don't want to edit it.
;;; -*- End Of Bookmark File Format Version Stamp -*-
(("tnsnames.ora"
 (filename . (concat (getenv "TNS_ADMIN") "/tnsnames.ora"))
 (front-context-string . "#\n# TNSNAMES.ORA")
 (rear-context-string)
 (position . 1))
)
```

Comment: What is the result of: `M-:` `(getenv "TNSADMIN")` ?

Comment: Thanks, you helped me spot a typo. I should have been using TNS_ADMIN, with an underscore. But it still doesn't work. getenv("TNS_ADMIN") returns a String starting with "/iusr/local" which is the expected value, but I still get 'Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p'

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... Yes that's really strange... Did you try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to check the full stack trace? (sorry I have to leave the office, I will be back in one hour).

Comment: Show where your code is used, in context. All you show is a list (and it's unquoted). If it were evaluated as shown it would raise an error because the car is a string. So probably what you show is either quoted or already the result of some evaluation. In that case, the `(concat...)` part is just a list, with car the symbol `concat`.

A guess is you're looking for backquote instead of quote, and for using a comma in front of the `(concat...)`. But it's impossible to tell because the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to conclude that the contents of .emacs.bmk is a data structure and not interpreted, and thus elisp functions like concat and getenv are not interpreted.

I found this link helpful in understanding the error message:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Wrong-Type-of-Argument.html